# Git clone without internet connection

Tags: python

```
git clone https://github.com/hzeller/rpi-rgb-led-matrix/
```

Is the command I have to send using internet on my Raspberry Pi

It will create a library. The problem is I do not have internet on my RPi.
Can someone tell me where (in what directory) the github project/library gets saved on the RPi? I'll just do it manually by downloading it on the PC and moving it to the Micro SD card, if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Put it where you want, it really doesn't matter.

A lot of people would use a sub-directory under their home directory.

It may be simpler to download the master.zip file for the git and copy that to the Pi.  It will be simpler to unzip on the Pi rather than unzipping on the PC and then copying the directory structure to the Pi.

Comment: so, i put the .zip file under the home category, and how do i unzip this on my RPi as you said to let it have the same effect of the example command (with internet) as given above?

Comment: @JonasAnon Assuming you are using the Pi user account you would put it      in something like this /home/pi/projects/ You will need to create the projects directory. You can unzip with the unzip command. More info on the unzip command can be found with this command man unzip.